# Building a Diet Using Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

**The Question**

Suppose a diet calls for 7 units of fats, 9 units of protein and 16 units of carbohydrates for the main meal. Suppose the dieter has 3 possible types of food to satisfy this requirement:

Food 1 which has 2 units of fat, 2 units of protein, 4 units of carbs
Food 2 which has 3 units of fat, 1 units of protein, and 2 units of carbs
Food 3 which has 1 unit of fat, 3 nits of protein and 5 units of carbs

Let $x,y,z$ denote the number of ounces of Food 1,Food 2 and Food 3 the dieter will consume. Find a linear system in the 3 unknowns $x,y,z$ whose solution will tell us how many ounces of each food must be consumed for the dieter to meet their requirement.

**My Work**

I've looked at this problem for 15 minutes now and still haven't made much progress. $x+y+z = 6f + 6p + 11c$ where $f=$ fats,$p=$ proteins, $c=$ carbs. I was definitely hoping for something that didn't have different units so that it could look more like a linear equation. Can anyone show me how to write out the sum of these 3 unknowns(or some multiple of them) so that I get something a bit more useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define "nutrient space" as a 3-dimensional space of fats, protiens and carbs, with units as ounces. A "food" is then a 3D point in this space, and a "diet" is a linear combination of "foods". We have foods 1 through 3,

$$
f_1 = [2, 2, 4]\\
f_2 = [3, 1, 2]\\
f_3 = [1, 3, 5]\\
$$

A diet is then a linear combination:

$$
d = xf_1 + yf_2 + zf_3
$$

And we simply wish to find $x, y, z$ such that

$$
d = [7, 9, 16]
$$

which I'm sure you can figure out ;)

Comment: took me a while to wrap my head around this (I just temporarily moved on from the question) but this is a good answer now that I've looked back on it. Thanks.